# Printing 2D array with forEach in C++, but without using auto keyword

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, c++17, range-based-loop

I have come across the solution to print the 2 D array using C++.

The ans was to use `auto` keyword:

for eg:

```
double nut_torques[4][5]; // this is my array with type double 
for (auto& rows : nut_torques) 
{
    for (auto cols : rows) 
    {
       std::cout << cols << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But can anyone tell me what if I don't want to use `aut`?

For example, if there is *1 D array* then using `double`(since my type is `double`) works:

```
for (double rows : array) {
}
```

I tried following for *2D array*, but this time double worked only for inner *foreach*:

```
for (auto& rows : nut_torques) 
{
    for (**double** cols : rows) 
    {
       std::cout << cols << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But the following did not work for me, when I tried adding `double` for both inner and outer *foreach*:

```
for (**double** rows : nut_torques) 
{
    std::cout << rows<<std::endl;

    for (**double** cols : rows) 
    {
        std::cout << cols << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

May I know the reason why we can't use double in outer *foreach* and what if I don't want to use auto then what shall I use there.

Also, if we `std::cout` array variable, then we get address to the first index. Then how come for single *foreach* this line works:

`for(double val: arrVariable)`

Does foreach automatically dereferences the `arrayVariable`  and does it automatically increments it?

Comment: Because outer `for` iterates not over doubles, but arrays of doubles.

Answer (score 1):

The outer `for` loop does not iterate over doubles, but rather over rows, which are saved as array. When you cout the array variable, you are basically printing the pointer, since array is saved as a pointer to the first element.

I believe this `for` loop uses iterators like `std::begin` and `std::end` to traverse the array. This is why you need the type shown below instead of `double *row` in the outer `for` loop, since you cannot call `std::begin` using a pointer.

This is how you would write it without `auto`. You have to write out the correct types by hand. The variables of outer `for` are references to arrays and the inner has doubles.

```cpp
for (double (&row)[5] : nut_torques) {
    for (double value : row) {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Basically the type of the outer loop is the same as type of `nut_torques[0]` and `nut_torques[0][0]` for the inner loop.

Comment: Hello,@Blaz, this answer works, thanks. Can you tell me any book from which I will know some small points like this which you have given.

Comment: Regarding C++ I only read C++ Primer. It does explain iterators as well. The main concept here is also present in other languages like Java or Python. The outer loop iterates over the first dimension (elements are arrays) and the inner one over the second dimension (values itself).